# Optimize Node.js command line app with Webpack and include node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'd like to optimize a Node.js command line app with a large number of files, including dependencies in node_modules.

What I'd like to do is bundle everything up in one file and minify/uglify. I'd like to include all the dependencies in node_modules that are not devDependencies defined in package.json.

Does this make sense? Anyone know how to do this?

My best guess is something like this:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {

  entry: "./entry.js",
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: "./dist",
    filename: "bundle.min.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})
  ]
};
```

perhaps Webpack includes the node_modules deps already? But does it exclude the devDependencies by default?

I figure I can shave 50ms - 200ms from the startime/runtime of the command line app, which would be a nice-to-have.

Comment: Looking for the exact same thing, only from a deployment perspective. Did you happen to find a solution?